# VC++ 2010 Intellisense does not see headers, but no error during compilation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, include, sdl

I am have compiled a test program with SDL. The program compiles fine and is working, but there is no intellisense for the files that i can include.

Including them: "SDL.h" does not give me an error. Intelisense works for all the SDL functions, so i cannot see what the problem might be.

My set up: Additional include directories : SDL-1.2.15\include\

EDIT: Giving it an absolute path, makes the intelisense work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution, seems to be a bug in VS, but when i changed the relative path to one using macros, it worked fine again. So I changed this:

```
SDL-1.2.15\include\
```

to this:

```
$(Project_Dir)\SDL-1.2.15\include\
```